# How to initialise a global instance of a bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

So I wanted to use the same instance of a bloc across the app so I created one out side the `main()` function and just import it to other files.

It works but as I need it to trigger an event in `initState` method, I am getting a null value when I try to use there like its not initialized yet.

This is what it kinda looks like

```
late TreatmentcardBloc treatmentcardBloc;

Future main() async {
  treatmentcardBloc = TreatmentcardBloc();
...
}
```

this is the error

> The following _CastError was thrown building
> BlocBuilder<TreatmentcardBloc, TreatmentcardState>(dirty,
> dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope], state:
> _BlocBuilderBaseState<TreatmentcardBloc, TreatmentcardState>#713fd): Null check operator used on a null value
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> BlocBuilder<TreatmentcardBloc, TreatmentcardState>
> file:///home/bihire/development/flutter/companion-project/mobile/lib/screens/d
> ashboard/treatments/treatment_screen.dart:179:35

where am I going wrong here and why if possible?

keep in mind when I force the page rebuild with new initialization it works. which kinda mean its the bloc instance that is being late to be created.

Comment: please share build method

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a `Global` class that initializes a `GlobalBloc` instance that I call `controller`. I then reference it as `global.controller` wherever I need it.

My main.dart looks something like this:

```
late Global global;
var rootKey = GlobalKey<_AppState>();

void main() async {
  ...

  // Initialize global manager
  global = Global();
  await global.initialize();

  runZonedGuarded(() => runApp(App(key: rootKey)), global.onUnhandledError);
}
```

`Global` initializes my global BLoC instance, called `controller`:

```
class Global {
  Future<void> initialize() async {  
    ...
    
    // Inizialize global controller
    controller = GlobalBloc();
  } 

  ...      
}
```

I then reference it as `global.controller` from my app pages:

```
global.controller.stream.listen((status) async { 
  switch (status) {
    case InitializedState: 
      ... 
      break;
    case ...
  }
});
```

Please note that I only use a global controller for functionality that is really common (e.g. app initializers, error handling, etc.), and I always create a dedicated controller for all pages and widgets that have a business logic.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of that bloc at the end of your bloc file. like this:

```
// inside Your bloc.dart file
class Bloc{
...
}
final bloc = Bloc();
```

then you will have access to your bloc everywhere inside the app.